# How to get specific text when clicking on button?

Tags: jquery

I want to get the specific text that is shown and tweet it out.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mOeXVM

below its my code:

```
function tweet () {
  var phrase = $(this).text();
  alert(phrase);
 // var phrase = document.getElementsByClassName('panel-body')[0];

  var tweetUrl = 'https://twitter.com/share?text=' +
    encodeURIComponent(phrase) ;

  window.open(tweetUrl);
}
```

Comment: Was going to post an answer but RatHat beat me to it, so here's the codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/WoQyym - Also, you spelled "Quotes" wrong, and your sentence should read "These are ra**n**dom quotes, some nice ones!"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using var `phrase= $(this).text()`, you are getting the `'Text'` of the clicked button since it's the element that called the function. Instead you need to get the `text` of the panel that's currently visible. The following jQuery should do the trick

```
function tweet () {
  var newarr = $('.panel-body:visible').text();
  alert(newarr);
  //var phrase = document.getElementsByClassName('panel-body')[0];

  var tweetUrl = 'https://twitter.com/share?text=' +
    encodeURIComponent(newarr) ;

  window.open(tweetUrl);
}
```

Comment: I believe you should change `encodeURIComponent(phrase)` to `encodeURIComponent(newarr)`.

Comment: @Santi you are absolutely correct. Just updated the code.